# MongoDB Concurrency

Tags: mongodb, database

I'm a little confused about MongoDB's read locking. How many concurrent read operations can a single collection support?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As written in the link given by tk : http://www.mongodb.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=7209296

> Read/Write Lock
>
> mongod uses a read/write lock for many
>   operations. **Any number of concurrent
>   read operations are allowed**, but
>   typically only one write operation
>   (although some write operations yield
>   and in the future more concurrency
>   will be added). The write lock
>   acquisition is greedy: a pending write
>   lock acquisition will prevent further
>   read lock acquisitions until
>   fulfilled.

Typical read/write lock

Answer (score 4):

You can check here: http://www.mongodb.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=7209296